# OpenCv android apk is huge

Tags: android, opencv, apk

Im using OpenCV native library in my android project. Its a hello world project with one CameraScreen and it already has 40mb. How can I reduce the size of the apk, since im not using most of the OpenCv library features?

I have jni folder with c++ code and imported OpenCVLibrary320?

Comment: ProGuard can help you with that. [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) you can read more about it.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović think the problem is with native c++ library of opencv...check this image: http://prntscr.com/em8zp8

Comment: Then, the only option is to manually strip unnecessary images. But that means that you will need to have different apks for different processor types, and that is horrible to manage on PlayStore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at these links:

[One](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/android-ndk-version-code-scheme-for-publishing-apks-per-architecture/)

[Two](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/android-ndk-a-guide-to-deploying-apps-with-native-libraries/)

Basically, what you want to do here:

1. Add this to your build.gradle file(Android brackets):

   ```
   android{
   splits {
       abi {
           enable true
           reset()
           include 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'x86_64'
           universalApk true
       }
   }

   project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]

   android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
       variant.outputs.each { output ->
           output.versionCodeOverride =
                   project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(
                           com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 10000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
       }
   }
   ```

What this is going to is that when you click to generate signed apk, it will generate number of apks.

[image]

The android.applicationVariants.all in gradle is going to create version codes for each of these apks, so you don't need to do it by yourself. With that in mind, you can just put each apk to the play store and everything will work fine from there.

**IMPORTANT**
When building your release apk, in new Android Studio, please select `Signature version V1`:

[image]

From more info and detailed explanation on all of this, please look through links that I supplied above.

Comment: I do so, but the size of APKs are still more than 50 mg. any solution?

Comment: I guess, we don't have to do all this if we use app bundle, right ?